# Adding custom paper size to printer driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer

I am attempting to print on an OKI Microline 5520 dot matrix printer. I am trying to print on a custom sized form, however I cannot select any custom paper sizes in the printing preferences.

I have tried the built in windows driver, and I have downloaded the latest drivers from the OKI website. The latest drivers open up some more paper sizes (fanfold types mostly), however I still can not select the custom form I have created.

Is there a way to enable a printer driver to use custom paper sizes?

I am using Windows 7, the custom paper size I need to use is 10" x 5.6". The closest fanfold paper size is 8.5" x 5.5", unfortunately this cuts off some of the text from the print.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was caused by the CUSTOMSIZE entry in the PaperSize feature of the driver.

*MaxPrintableWidth was set to 6120, which was smaller than that required by the custom paper size. Increasing this value to the Paper Width in Inches * the width value in *MasterUnits: PAIR(x, x) allows the paper size to appear.

Multiplying the width of the custom paper size in inches by the width component of *MasterUnits: PAIR(x, x) in the driver file gives the value the minimum *MaxPrintableWidth you need to set in the driver file.

In this case, it was 10 * 720, so *MaxPrintableWidth: 7200 allows the paper size to be set.